# Find rows that have the same value on a column in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

In a [member] table, some rows have the same value for the `email` column.

```
login_id | email
---------|---------------------
john     | john123@hotmail.com
peter    | peter456@gmail.com
johnny   | john123@hotmail.com
...
```

Some people used a different login_id but the same email address, no unique constraint was set on this column. Now I need to find these rows and see if they should be removed.

What SQL statement should I use to find these rows? (MySQL 5)

Answer (score 461, accepted):

This query will give you a list of email addresses and how many times they're used, with the most used addresses first.

```sql
SELECT email,
       count(*) AS c
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY email
HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY c DESC
```

If you want the full rows:

```
select * from table where email in (
    select email from table
    group by email having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: `count(1)` works equally well, and is more performant. (Learned that trick from [so] ;-)

Comment: @jpaugh, might not want to use `count(1)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better

Comment: created what was essentially infinite recursion or something on mysql resulting in a dead database due to "too many connections" :-/

Comment: Worked for SQLite as well. Thank you!

Comment: @jpaugh nowadays no performance difference between `count(*)` and `count(1)`, query analyzers of DBMS are pretty smart and not going to load whole row to execute `count(*)`. Test it yourself (and don't forget to disable cache before test).

Comment: @kdmitry I'll take your word for it. Honestly, it was always bananas to me that query analyzers _couldn't_ always do that. It seems like low-hanging fruit,

Comment: How do I use multiple columns in group by and want full rows?

Comment: @PriyankaRao see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149330/482828

Answer (score 81):

```
select email from mytable group by email having count(*) >1
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work with Postgres, this one does.

Comment: @HLGEM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359879/postgresql-get-records-having-similar-column-values

Answer (score 17):

Here is query to find `email`'s which are used for more then one `login_id`:

```
SELECT email
FROM table
GROUP BY email
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

You'll need second (of nested) query to get list of `login_id` by `email`.

Answer (score 12):

First part of accepted answer does not work for MSSQL.
This worked for me:

```
select email, COUNT(*) as C from table 
group by email having COUNT(*) >1 order by C desc
```

Answer (score 6):

use this if your email column contains empty values

```
 select * from table where email in (
    select email from table group by email having count(*) > 1 and email != ''
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys :-) I used the below because I only cared about those two columns and not so much about the rest. Worked great

```
  select email, login_id from table
    group by email, login_id
    having COUNT(email) > 1
```

Comment: In the case in question, COUNT(email) would always be 1, so you query will return nothing.

Comment: No, the query actually gave me the data I needed, which is distinctly the email and login_name of those who have the same email

Comment: If you group by email *and* login_id, you will count amount of rows for same email and login, and those are distinct in your example, so count will be always be 1. Here is the fiddle with your query that returns 0 rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bbcaf/3

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question but this is more for someone else who might have the same problem and I think this is more accurate to what was wanted.

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE email = (Select email From member Where login_id = john123@hotmail.com)
```

This will return all records that have john123@hotmail.com as a login_id value.

Answer (score 3):

This works best

> Screenshot
> [image]

```
SELECT RollId, count(*) AS c 
    FROM `tblstudents` 
    GROUP BY RollId 
    HAVING c > 1 
    ORDER BY c DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the entire record as you want using the condition with inner select query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   member
WHERE  email IN (SELECT email
                 FROM   member
                 WHERE  login_id = abcd.user@hotmail.com)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very late to this thread, but I had a similar situation and the following worked on MySQL. The following query will also return all the rows that match the condition of duplicate emails

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMAIL IN 
       (SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT EMAIL FROM TABLE GROUP BY EMAIL HAVING COUNT(EMAIL) > 1) 
        AS X);
```