# Mysql: Calculate visit frequency

Tags: mysql, datetime, distance

I have this table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE hits (ip bigint, page VARCHAR(256), agent VARCHAR(1000), 
                              date datetime)
```

and I want to calculate googlebot visit frequency for every page.

```
... WHERE agent like '%Googlebot%' group by page
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT page,
         COUNT(*)
    FROM hits
   WHERE agent LIKE '%Googlebot%'
GROUP BY page
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select page, count(1) as visits
  from hits
 where agent like '%Googlebot%'
 group by page;
```

Comment: @stereofrog: It's basically the same. You just care about counting rows, so count(1) is all you need. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better