# Mysql: Calculate averge time between visits

Tags: mysql, datetime, datediff

This related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3743447/387194).

I have this table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE hits (ip bigint, page VARCHAR(256), agent VARCHAR(1000), 
                              date datetime)
```

and I want to calculate average time between googlebot visit for every page.

```
... WHERE agent like '%Googlebot%' group by page order by date
```

Something like

```
select datediff('2010-09-18 04:20:47', '2010-09-16 05:23:04')
```

but for every date in table
If there is no mysql way, how can I do this in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT page, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(date), MAX(date)) / (COUNT(*)-1) FROM hits 
WHERE agent like '%Googlebot%' GROUP BY page;
```

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a, b)` returns the difference in seconds between the date expressions a and b. For each page, the query finds the date of the first and last visit and the total count of visits, and calculates the arithmetic average.