# number of rows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to count or know the number of rows a table has without scaning all the table, maybe using `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: You don't mean like select count(*) from table do you?

Comment: count(primary key) will not scan all the table, so dont be afraid of using it. Check my answer for a more detailed info.

Comment: @MestreLion - It **will** scan the whole table. With a CI the leaf level **is** the table. It needs to scan the leaf pages themselves as this information is not available in upper levels (intermediate level pages only have a key and pointer for each **page** in the level below they have no information on how many rows each child page contains)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you need a exact count, you will need to do a `COUNT(*)` which will scan the clustered index.

You can get a rough count using the `sys.partitions` schema, as shown here http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-rowcount-using-sql-server-system-view-sys-partitions.aspx

Update: To get the count into a variable:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT;
SELECT @cnt = SUM(rows)
FROM sys.partitions
WHERE
  index_id IN (0, 1)
  AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyDB.dbo.MyTable');
SELECT @cnt;
```

Comment: +1 The only answer so far to address the "without scanning all the table" part of the question.

Comment: I red the info in the link, it says it is fast to use SQL Server system view (sys.partitions). Do you know if outperforms `select count(*) from table` for lets say a table with lots of rows (>100,000,000)?

Comment: @darkcminor - It will easily out perform it as it just has to retrieve a number from the system tables as opposed to scanning and counting 100 million rows. (probably x00,000 logical reads depending on how many rows in a page)

Comment: correct, very nice answer, do you care if I post the code from that page here?

Comment: @darkcminor It will definitely be *faster*, since - at the very least - it won't need to place shared locks on the rows, however it will be less accurate.

Comment: Also do you know a way to set a @variable this result?

Comment: sys.partitions will be faster, but it wont be accurate. If all wou want is a rough estimative, go fo it. But for accuracy, theres no other way than COUNT(*). But dont worry: its an indexed count, not a full table scan

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table
```

will return the number of rows

Answer (score 3):

There is no `ROW_NUMBER` in SQL Server, just Oracle. Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(primary_key) FROM table
```

Where `primary key` the primary key column of your table.

Since its a primary key, its is already indexed, so SQL can count it without scanning the whole table (it uses a clustered index to be precise, which is *much* faster than a full table scan)

You could also use `sys.indexes` schema, but its not accurate, and you would need database admin priviledges to access, and your application database user is not supposed to have grants in that schema

Comment: COUNT(PK) is actually slower than COUNT(*)

Comment: @simon I highly doubt it. Can you please provide sample code where it will be slower?

Comment: @Simon: i dont see why, since internally SQL uses the primary key index to count the rows then COUNT(*) is used. If same index is used for both counts, performance should be pretty similar, if not the same.

Comment: Ok, so im seeing mixed bag here, but http://lists.mysql.com/maxdb/18486 shows one example. My bad - COUNT(ID) seems the way to go

Comment: (couldve sworn i read that somewhere - i even changed all my queries :()

Comment: Ok just reading more on the subject - choose the COUNT() carefully depending on your schema, DBMS and storage engine: http://mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better

Comment: SQL Server Specific : Count(*) can use any index (non-filtered) and will select the narrowest. Count(PK) must use an index with the PK in it - however, if the table is clustered on that PK, then the PK is contained within every NC index anyway - so SQL will then still choose the narrowest index to count.

Comment: @Scrum the way to construct an example of a slower run counting the PK would be a non-clustered primary key that was quite wide vs counting a narrow non-clustered non-filtered index.

Comment: @Andrew - That isn't the case (your last comment). `COUNT(PK)` just appears in the plan as `Count(*)` anyway. Try `create table #foo(wide char(800) primary key nonclustered,narrow int); create nonclustered index ix on #foo(narrow); insert into #foo SELECT object_id, object_id FROM sys.objects; select COUNT(wide) from #foo;`

Comment: You're right, had to test some examples to see the exact optimization going on - tag on to your example select count(distinct wide) from #foo - I'm asking for the count of distinct values in the wide column. The query plan shows it accessing foo.ix only - which we know does not contain those values - so how can it guarentee the right answer? if I remove the PK aspect of that column, it then counts from the table. The optimizer is taking a short cut by saying - if its the PK, I know its unique, so its same as count(*), use the narrowest index again - unexpected but smart.

Comment: @Andrew - BTW I just tested and `wide` doesn't even have to be the PK. It is sufficient that it is marked as `NOT NULL` for the narrower index to be used. If it is non nullable and unique (e.g. PK) then SQL Server will also use the narrow index for `select COUNT(DISTINCT wide) from #foo;`

Comment: Whoops just realised that the 2nd part of my comment just repeats what you were already saying!

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party here, but in SQL Server 2005 on, you could also use the `sp_spaceused` stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @rowCount AS INT
DECLARE @spaceUsed TABLE(
    [Name] varchar(64), 
    [Rows] INT,
    [Reserved] VARCHAR(50),
    [Data] VARCHAR(50),
    [Index_Size] VARCHAR(50),
    [Unused] VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @spaceUsed EXEC sp_spaceused 'MyTableName'
SET @rowCount = (SELECT TOP 1 [Rows] FROM @spaceUsed)
SELECT @rowCount AS 'Row Count'
```

I've gotten into the habit of using `sp_spaceused` in place of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table` because it is much faster.  It will most likely not be as accurate as COUNT(*), however.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe you mean this but ill give it a try:

```
select count(*) from table
```

Comment: Again: this **will** scan the whole table (not recommended for tables with millions of rows....)