# Assign to a variable the number of rows a table has in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How would you assign a variable the total number of rows a table has in `SQL Server`?

Comment: Where is the variable in? Your client? SQL Server?

Comment: So, on the server itself, not the application?

Comment: I believe you have asked the same question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199412/number-of-rows-sql-server

Comment: Well, here I am asking how to assign that number to a variable, other question was how to do that efficiently

Comment: @darkcminor, I agree with @reggie, the previous question already assigned the result to a variable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
Declare @VariableName int

Select @VariableName=count(1) from TableName
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, still trying to figure out the simple things in life! :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table`

For more details, please provide more detail.