# Count rows in more than one table with tSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

I need to count rows in more than one table in SQL Server 2008. I do this:

```
select count(*) from (select * from tbl1 union all select * from tbl2)
```

But it gives me an error of incorrect syntax near ). Why?

PS. The actual number of tables can be more than 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have different number of columns in your tables try this way

```
 SELECT count(*) 
 FROM (
      SELECT NULL as columnName 
      FROM tbl1 
          UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL 
      FROM tbl2
     ) T
```

Comment: Good point. Thanks. Can you explain though, what does "NULL a" stand for?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you select from tables if you need only count of rows, that's why it can be just a 'NULL' value and a is alias for that column. To make it clearer I wrote 'NULL as a'

Comment: Oh, so I can technically drop "as a" and just do "select NULL from tbl1", right?

Comment: right and you'll get all rows without values, but it's enough for counting.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

You have to give a name to your derived table

```
select count(*) from 
(select * from tbl1 union all select * from tbl2)a
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to alias the `SELECT` in the `FROM` clause:

```
select count(*) 
from 
(
   select * from tbl1 
   union all 
   select * from tbl2
) AS SUB
```

You also need to ensure that the `*` in both tables `tbl1` and `tbl2` return exactly the same number of columns and they have to be matched in their type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like doing the union before doing the count.  It gives the SQL optimizer an opportunithy to choose to do more work.

AlexK's (deleted) solution is fine.  You could also do:

```
select (select count(*) from tbl1) + (select count(*) from tbl2) as cnt
```

Comment: Hah, I didn't think about this simple one. Just from curiosity, you put "as cnt" after the second SELECT, was that the intention? Or, do I need parenths there?

Comment: Also since you brought up efficiency, two questions. 1. Would it help to replace "count(*)" with "NULL as columnName" as was suggested by hgulyan. 2. And, is there a resource/document that can be used for tSQL efficiency/speed optimization?

Comment: If you want to do this efficiently, then don't scan the table at all . . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199412/number-of-rows-sql-server.  My understanding is that SQL Server will use indexes (if available) for count(*), so the execution performance should be the same as count(1).