# MySQL-Count rows in more than one table with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

When I'm run below the query separately getting the correct result.

```
SELECT COUNT(hospital_id) FROM `hospital` WHERE org_id='1' // Result: 0
SELECT COUNT(pharmacy_id) FROM `pharmacy` WHERE org_id='1' // Result: 1
SELECT COUNT(fire_station_id) FROM `fire_station` WHERE org_id='1' // Result: 3
SELECT COUNT(als_id) FROM `als` WHERE org_id='1' // Result: 3
SELECT COUNT(units_id) FROM `units` WHERE org_id='1'; //Result: 3
```

But I need all the result in single using any concept of MySQL.

My try:

```
SELECT COUNT(hospital_id) AS Hospital FROM `hospital` WHERE org_id='1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(pharmacy_id) AS Pharmacy FROM `pharmacy` WHERE org_id='1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(fire_station_id) AS Station FROM `fire_station` WHERE org_id='1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(als_id) AS Als FROM `als` WHERE org_id='1'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(units_id) AS Units FROM `units` WHERE org_id='1';
```

**This is my current result:**

```
    +------------+
    |   Hospital |
    +------------+
    |          0 |
    |          1 |
    |          3 |
    +------------+
```

**This is my desired result:**

```
+------------+------------+------------+-------+--------+
|   Hospital |   Pharmacy |   Station  |  Als  |   Units|
+------------+------------+------------+-------+--------+
|          0 |          1 |         3  |     3 |      3 |
+------------+------------+------------+-------+--------+
```

I'm also refer the Stack Question [Count rows in more than one table with tSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298011/count-rows-in-more-than-one-table-with-tsql)
But not getting the desired result.
Please update my query or suggest any other concept of MySQL.

Thanks To ALL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your specific query is `UNION`.  Use `UNION ALL`.  In fact, *always* use `UNION ALL`, unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

In any case, your queries are close.  Put them as subqueries in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(hospital_id) AS Hospital FROM `hospital` WHERE org_id='1') as hospital,
       (SELECT COUNT(pharmacy_id) AS Pharmacy FROM `pharmacy` WHERE org_id='1') as pharmacy,
       (SELECT COUNT(fire_station_id) AS Station FROM `fire_station` WHERE org_id='1') as Station,
       (SELECT COUNT(als_id) AS Als FROM `als` WHERE org_id='1') as als,
       (SELECT COUNT(units_id) AS Units FROM `units` WHERE org_id='1') as units;
```

You can also put the subqueries in the `FROM` clause and use `CROSS JOIN` to combine them.

Comment: This is working fine and good explanation. Thanks. It's really good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(hospital_id) FROM hospital WHERE org_id='1') as Hospital,
    (SELECT COUNT(pharmacy_id) FROM pharmacy WHERE org_id='1') as Pharmacy,
    (SELECT COUNT(fire_station_id) FROM fire_station WHERE org_id='1') as Station,
    (SELECT COUNT(als_id) FROM als WHERE org_id='1') as Als,
    (SELECT COUNT(units_id) FROM units WHERE org_id='1') as Units;
```