# A mysql query: couple of conditions matching in the same column

Tags: mysql, select, count, conditional-statements

I have this table named "events" in my mysql database:

```
+-----+-----------+------------------------------+------------+
| ID  | CATEGORY  | NAME                         | TYPE       |
+-----+-----------+------------------------------+------------+
| 1   | 1         | Concert                      | music      |
| 2   | 2         | Basketball match             | indoors    |
| 3   | 1         | Theather play                | outdoors   |
| 4   | 1         | Concert                      | outdoors   |
+-----+-----------+------------------------------+------------+
```

I need a query to count the events with category 1 and which type is music and also outdoors
Meaning that from the table above the count should be only 1: there are three events with category 1
but only "Concert" has type outdoor and music (ID 1 and ID 4).

What would be that query? Can that be done?

Comment: @Mat Are you sure you payed enough attention to the question? It doesn't look basic to me.

Comment: i have one that works for what i think is what you want but for some reason i can't post it...

Comment: SELECT ID, COUNT(CATEGORY) FROM events WHERE CATEGORY=1 AND TYPE='music' AND TYPE='outdoors' GROUP BY ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT e1.name)
FROM `events` AS e1
JOIN `events` AS e2 ON e1.name = e2.name
WHERE e1.category = 1 
    AND e2.category = 1 
    AND e1.type = 'music' 
    AND e2.type = 'outdoor'
```

Or a harder to understand way, but way faster than the previous one:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT `name`
    FROM `events`
    WHERE `category` = 1
    GROUP BY `name`
    HAVING SUM( `type` = 'music') * SUM( `type` = 'outdoor' ) >= 1
) AS notNeeded
```

Comment: The second query is not the same as the first. The first is correct, the second one not.

Comment: I don't agree that this indicates a bad structure. [Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) often arises in normalised databases. How would you restructure it?

Comment: @Johan Apart from a missing alias what isn't correct about it? Also I added the alias.

Comment: @Alin, the second query will also yield rows that have 3x `music` types and no `outdoor`

Comment: @Johan You were right. I assumed the `music` and `type` combination unique. I corrected it. Also added a correction for the first one based on the same observation. Thank you!

Comment: I agree it looks as though `category` is functionally dependant upon `name` and there should be some separation out but at some point you are still going to have a junction table with `eventid, type` that needs this kind of query.

Comment: @Alin, wow a thing of beauty, query 2 will still break if `type` is allowed to be NULL, but you got my vote.

Comment: @Martin I removed my comment about normalization. After some thinking I must admit that there actually may be a situation in which this structure is in normal form. So there's no point in assuming conditions he didn't provide.

Comment: @Johan Why? Could you explain a bit?

Answer (score 2):

For 2 criteria I would use Alin's answer. An approach you can use for greater numbers is below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT `name`
        FROM   `events`
        WHERE  `category` = 1
               AND `type` IN ( 'outdoors', 'music' )
        GROUP  BY `name`
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `type`) = 2) t
```

Comment: Yeah... I wrote the first approach because it's easier to understand, but it's a terrible choice even for 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
Select count(*), group_concat(TYPE SEPARATOR ',') as types 
from events where category = 1 
HAVING LOCATE('music', types) and  LOCATE('outdoors', types)
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` AS e1
LEFT JOIN `events` AS e2 USING (`name`)
WHERE e1.`category` = 1 AND e2.`category` = 1 AND e1.`type` = 'music' AND e2.`type` = 'outdoors'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    WHERE category=1
    AND type='music' AND type IN (SELECT type
                                  FROM table
                                  WHERE type = 'outdoor')
```

one line keeps resetting my connection. wth? i'll try posting as a comment

Comment: anybody know why i couldn't type that without my connection being refused?

Answer (score -2):

Select count(distinct ID) as 'eventcount' from events where Category = '1' and Type in('music','outdoor')

Comment: count(*) is faster, anyway you need a self-join, see Alin's answer.

Comment: @Martin, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better and countless and countless links on just about every SQL blog

Comment: @Martin, but I guess I should have written `count(*) is never slower, sometimes the same and sometimes faster`

Comment: @Johan - Agreed `id` sounds like the PK so definitely in SQL Server it makes no odds.