# How to update database records based on values in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have `USERS` TABLE that contains the following fields `_id` `name` `number_of_posts`

and i have `POSTS` TABLE  that contains the following fields `_id` `user_id` `post_text`

no the relationship between the `users` and `posts` is `one- to -many` i.e one user have many post

the question is how to update the `number_of_posts` in `users` table such that it will hold the number of post in the `posts` table

**UPDATE**

I have these tables filled with about hundreds of records  there is no way to use the trigger to update the number_of_posts .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a trigger on the posts table. Every time a post is inserted, update the number_of_posts on the users table.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html

**Update:** full worked solution

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users (  
   _id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,   
   name varchar(50) not null, 
   number_of_posts integer not null default 0
);

drop table if exists posts;
create table posts (  
   _id bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,   
   user_id bigint unsigned not null, 
   post_text text
);

-- Populate with dummy data
insert into users (name) values ('Bob'), ('Sally');
insert into posts (user_id, post_text) 
    values (1, 'First!!'), (1, 'Second...'), 
           (2, 'Post 1'), (2, 'another post'), (2, 'more posts');

-- One-time update of users table
update users u
set u.number_of_posts = (      
  select count(0) from posts p
  where u._id = p.user_id      
);

-- trigger to keep post count up to date when future posts are made
drop trigger if exists trg_post_count;
delimiter $$

create trigger trg_post_count
after insert on posts
for each row 
begin
    select count(0) into @post_count 
    from posts
    where user_id = NEW.user_id;

    update users
    set number_of_posts = @post_count
    where _id = NEW.user_id;
end;
$$

delimiter ;

-- test trigger
insert into posts (user_id) values (2);
select * from users;
```

Comment: Yes, same result. Some say `count(0)` is cleaner/faster, I don't know if there's any basis for that. Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better

Answer (score 2):

Below given sample script shows how to get the number of posts associated with a user by joining both `users` and `posts` table using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then uses `GROUP BY` on the *_id* field in *users* table to fetch the posts count.

[**Click here to view the sample in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0032a/2)

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    _id     INT NOT NULL
  , name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts 
(
    _id     INT NOT NULL
  , _userid INT NOT NULL
  , name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (_id, name) VALUES
  (1, 'user 1'),
  (2, 'user 2'),
  (3, 'user 3');

INSERT INTO posts (_id, _userid, name) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'post 1'),
  (2, 1, 'post 2'),
  (3, 2, 'post 3');

SELECT          u._id
            ,   u.name
            ,   COUNT(p._id) number_of_posts
FROM            users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts p
ON              u._id = p._userid
GROUP BY        u._id;
```

*Output*:

```
_ID NAME    NUMBER_OF_POSTS
--- ------  ---------------
1   user 1         2
2   user 2         1
3   user 3         0
```

Answer (score 1):

As a one time update, try this, but the trigger solution is the right one to keep it current:

```
UPDATE users AS u SET u.number_of posts = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts AS p WHERE p.user_id=u.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

As dwurf suggested, I would definitely recommend putting this in a trigger to keep the field up-to-date.  However, I completely disagree with him that it should simply be a number that you increment on each update.  That's fragile and error prone.  You should use the following query to figure out exactly how many posts each user has:

```
update
  users
set 
  number_of_posts = ( 
    select
      count(0)
    from
      posts p
    where
      p.user_id = users.id
    )   
;
```