# Counting multiple entries / statistics

Tags: mysql

I want to add a survey to a website. And a good survey needs a reporting. Some basic reports are done. Now I want to put some cream on the coffee ...

The table with sample data:

```
mysql> select * from u001;
+----+----------+------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | drink    | sex        | age   | date                |
+----+----------+------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Beer     | m          | 30-39 | 2012-10-17 23:17:52 |
|  2 | Milk     | f          | 10-19 | 2012-10-18 00:15:59 |
|  3 | Milk     | f          | 20-29 | 2012-10-18 23:33:07 |
|  4 | Tea      | m          | 30-39 | 2012-10-20 22:47:08 |
|  5 | Water    | f          | 20-29 | 2012-10-20 22:47:30 |
|  6 | Milk     | m          | 30-39 | 2012-10-20 22:51:22 |
+----+----------+------------+-------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to get a result that counts how many women/men likes Tea/Beer/etc.
A desired result like this:

```
+-------+-----+---------+
| drink | sex | counted |
+-------+-----+---------+
| Beer  | m   | 1       |
| Milk  | f   | 2       |
| Tea   | m   | 1       |
| Water | f   | 1       |
| Milk  | m   | 1       |
+-------+-----+---------+
```

Have anyone some suggestions or solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT drink, sex, COUNT(id) counted
FROM   u001
GROUP BY drink, sex
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46fbc/4)

Comment: COUNT(*) is normally not a good idea because if there are covering indexes, the query will probably not use them.

Comment: @Francisco, Do you have a source for that?

Comment: [COUNT(*) vs. COUNT(1) vs. COUNT(pk): which is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better) according on this post, it has no difference, `COUNT(*)` counts `null` while `COUNT(colName)` counts everythingexceptnull.

Comment: I have no source and most probably the rdbms is smart enough to optimize that, but since you want to count the rows that belong to that group and there's a way to tell the different rows (the primary key) there's no need to specify everything is it? I stand corrected though.

Comment: I will run some tests locally to see exactly what does MySQL do.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for this really quick and helpful response! Maybe I couln'd see the forest for the trees ...

Comment: @FranciscoSoto here's another [interesting blog about COUNT(*) vs COUNT(colName)](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)

Answer (score 2):

```
select drink, sex, count(id) from u001 group by drink, sex
```