# Mysql group by query taking 30+ sec to execute

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute following query

```
select COUNT(*) from tbl_impressions group by spackage
```

and it took approximately 40 seconds to execute it at first but after a few time same query is executing within 2 seconds.

Does any one know the reason?

PS: All the tables are already indexed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great. We can't read minds, so, please, add your table structure and `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: Query is compiling and the optimizer finds an execution plan,afterwards everything is cached.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this happens is the following:

> The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with
>   the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical
>   statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the
>   query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again. The
>   query cache is shared among sessions, so a result set generated by one
>   client can be sent in response to the same query issued by another
>   client.

Please for further documentation look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Thanks Christos Paisios