# Query to count the number record contain text

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count the number records based on the text in the table

Am having Table Structure Like this

```
SN_ID           NUMBER                      
PERSON_ID       NUMBER      
NOTICE_TYPE     VARCHAR2
```

and the contents of the table like this

```
    SN_ID  PERSON_ID   NOTICE_TYPE
  -------+-----------+--------------
    1      5           Appreciation
    2      5           Warning
    3      1           Warning
    4      5           Incident
    5      2           Warning
    6      5           Warning
```

I want to count the number Appreciation, Warning and Incident records for the person with an `Id = 5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select Notice_type, count(*) from [Table] 
where person_id=5
group by notice_type
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT NOTICE_TYPE, count(SN_ID) 
FROM [Table] 
WHERE PERSON_ID = 5
GROUP BY NOTICE_TYPE
```

This is slightly different from **MikkaRin** answer.

Difference is **`count(SN_ID)`**. I took only one column here. Because it is more optimized method than taking whole column into the **`count()`** function. This will affected to large queries.

p.s. actually we should get the primary key into the **`count()`** function. Here SN_ID look like the PK.

Comment: `Count(pk)` being faster than `Count(*)` is a misconception. Read  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710703/1200185) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1221649/1200185)

Comment: Yes. The SN_ID is looks like a pk here. And I edited it.