# Count the number of students and display in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Student and Course Table:

```
Student(Roll_no(primary), Name, Course_id(foreign))
Course(Course_no(primary), Course_name)
```

How will I retrieve:

a. The table with the details of Courses in which more than 2 students got admitted.

b. The Course table along with a count column.

What I tried for the first problem:

```
 SELECT * FROM Course WHERE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student GROUP BY Course_no WHERE COUNT(*) > 2);
```

I'm not sure what I did, but that didn't work. I am new to Database System 
.

Sample:
Student Table

```
    +---------+----------+----------+-----------+
    | Roll_no | Name     | Semester | Course_no |
    +---------+----------+----------+-----------+
    |       1 | a        |        3 |       101 |
    |       2 | b        |        5 |       101 |
    |       3 | c        |        3 |       101 |
    |       4 | c        |        3 |       101 |
    |       5 | d        |        3 |       101 |
    |       7 | b        |        4 |       102 |
    +---------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Course Table

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Course_no | Course_name |
+-----------+-------------+
|       101 | BCA         |
|       102 | BSC         |
+-----------+-------------+
```

For the First Part I expect a table like:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Course_no | Course_name |
+-----------+-------------+
|       101 | BCA         |
+-----------+-------------+
```

For the Second part I expect a table like

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| Course_no | Course_name |Total   |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
|       101 | BCA         |5       |
|       102 | BSC         |1       |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from thoes table and expect result?

Comment: What mean "... and display in another table" in SQL context? What is exactly question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Part:

You need to use `JOIN` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT c.Course_no,c.Course_name
FROM Course c 
INNER JOIN Student s on c.Course_no = s.Course_id
GROUP BY c.Course_no,c.Course_name
HAVING count(1) > 2
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/387386/3*

Second part:

You need to `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` `COUNT`

```
SELECT c.Course_no,c.Course_name,count(1) 'totle'
FROM Course c 
INNER JOIN Student s on c.Course_no = s.Course_id
GROUP BY c.Course_no,c.Course_name
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bad7e3/1*

Comment: What does count(1) mean ? Is it similar to count(*) ?

Comment: @rgo `count(1)` is the same with `COUNT(*)` on this question.

Comment: If It was an another number but 2 would still count(1) be same as count(*) for this case ?

Comment: i disagree that `COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better/2710703#2710703

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank for your refer,But I think the optimizer recognizes it for what it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server

Comment: That link you have provided is SQL Server not MySQL

Comment: If I query till 'SELECT c.Course_no,c.Course_name
FROM Course c 
INNER JOIN Student s on c.Course_no = s.Course_id
GROUP BY c.Course_no,c.Course_name'  Then I get the result as the course sample table.  


Is it that the size of each row is hidden as a temporary value ? After introducing the having clause I get the required result. How is count working here.

Comment: @rgo `count` will counting after group by clause .You can take a look at Query order of execution.:)
 https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution