# update rows with duplicate entries

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysql-error-1093

I have the same situation as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786533/find-rows-that-have-the-same-value-on-a-column-in-mysql), but I don't want to select the rows, I want to update these rows.

I used the [solution Scott Saunders made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786533/find-rows-that-have-the-same-value-on-a-column-in-mysql/1786568#1786568):

```
select * from table where email in (
    select email from table group by email having count(*) > 1
)
```

That worked, but I wanted to change/update a row-value in these entries, so I tried:

```
UPDATE `members` SET `banned` = "1" WHERE `ip` IN (
    SELECT `ip` FROM `members` GROUP BY `ip` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

but I get this error:

> You can't specify target table
>   'members' for update in FROM
>   clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an intermediate subquery to get around the 1093 error:

```
UPDATE `members` 
   SET `banned` = '1' 
 WHERE `ip` IN (SELECT x.ip
                  FROM (SELECT `ip` 
                          FROM `members` 
                      GROUP BY `ip` 
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x)
```

Otherwise, use a JOIN on a derived table:

```
UPDATE MEMBERS 
  JOIN (SELECT `ip` 
          FROM `members` 
      GROUP BY `ip` 
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x ON x.ip = MEMBERS.ip
   SET banned = '1'
```

Comment: +1  Nice! Nothing like a tiny workaround. Curious if MySQL would support something like: `UPDATE M SET... FROM Members M WHERE... GROUP BY ... HAVING....` (no MySQL here ATM). Thoughts?

Comment: @p.campbell: I think the JOIN option would be cleaner.  Too bad the JOIN in UPDATE & DELETE isn't supported in most other databases.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you can't update the `members` table based on criteria of the `members` table. In your case, you are attempting to update the `members` table based on a subquery of the `members` table. In the process you are changing that table. Think of it like a chicken before the egg paradox.

You'll need to make a temporary reference table or save/paste the ip ranges in order to run that update statement.