# Finding duplicate rows based on value in different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I've this table with the following data:

```
CaseID|ProductNr|CodeNr|Test
    1 |1234     |444   |No
    1 |1235     |444   |No
    1 |1236     |444   |No
    1 |1237     |666   |No
    1 |1238     |777   |No
    2 |1244     |555   |No
    2 |1245     |555   |No
```

I want a query that find all the "ProductNr" that has the same "CodeNr" within the same "CaseID".

E.g. if `.. Where CaseId = 1` the result should be as below:

```
CaseID|ProductNr|CodeNr|Test
    1 |1234     |444   |No
    1 |1235     |444   |No
    1 |1236     |444   |No
```

I'm using sql server

It should be possible to change the CaseId value.. The CaseId value should be a parameter.. because the query need to be a part af stored procedure..

Comment: Either EXISTS, or self-join.

Comment: according to your criteria, shouldn't the result be every row with `CaseId = 1`?, or is it another requirement that there must be duplicates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find duplicates across multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149210/how-do-i-find-duplicates-across-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query shows you those rows of `YourTable` whose `CaseID` is equals to the given parameter and that there is at least one row on the same table with the same `CaseID`, the same `CodeNr`, but different `ProductNr`. This is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM YourTable i
   WHERE t.CaseID = i.CaseID AND t.ProductNr <> i.ProductNr AND t.CodeNr = i.CodeNr
) AND t.CaseID = @CaseID
```

Comment: Hi thanks.. but it should be possible to change the CaseId value.. The CaseId value should be a parameter.. because the query need to be a part af stored procedure..

Comment: @Balatharan  Edited to add `@CaseID` parameter

Comment: Hi Jesus, your query give me the desired result thanks a lot.. just a another question does the EXISTS give any problem, someone told me to not use EXISTS, i don't know quite way?

Comment: No problem with `EXISTS` at all. But if you want your query to be fast, add an index to the table on the columns: `CaseID` and `CodeNr`. `CREATE INDEX IX_YourTable_CaseID_CodeNr ON YourTable(CaseID, CodeNr) INCLUDE (ProductNr)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
SELECT CaseID, ProductNr, CodeNr, Test
FROM (
  SELECT CaseID, ProductNr, CodeNr, Test,
         COUNT(CodeNr) OVER (PARTITION BY CodeNr) AS cnt
  FROM mytable
  WHERE CaseID = 1) AS t
WHERE t.cnt > 1
```

`COUNT` window function is applied on `CodeNr` partitions. Any record that belongs to a partition with a population greater than 1 will be returned by this query.

**Note:** You can additionally use `RANK` in case of more than one groups of duplicate records, so as to discern between records that belong to separate `CodeNr` groups.

**Note2:** This query works as long as each `CodeNr` partition contains only unique `ProductNr` values.

Comment: My initial attempt was at the wrong path, had to completely rewrite my answer. Apologies.