# Suppose multiple column with 1000 records in a table, how to find the duplicate record in whole table?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, duplicates

Suppose multiple column with 1000 records in a table, how to find the duplicate record in whole table?

Please help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use HAVING with count() > 1.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated id's:

```
select s.id, t.* 
from [stuff] s
join (
    select name, city, count(*) as qty
    from [stuff]
    group by name, city
    having count(*) > 1
) t on s.name = t.name and s.city = t.city
```

answer is also posted in this topic: [How do I find duplicates across multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149210/how-do-i-find-duplicates-across-multiple-columns)