# Finding duplicates based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all rows which are duplicates across different locations.
Table data is as below,

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| Assetno  |  SerialNo  |   StickerNo  |     location  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1234     |   QWR      |   12ERT      |     123       |
| 1234     |   QWR      |   12ERT      |     567       |
| 7888     |   ytu      |   67UI       |     456       |
| 9000     |   UIO      |   OPIO9      |     8         |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Like in the above table I need to find rows like row number 1 and 2.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY <> ORDER BY <>`? What did you try, show us your attempt and the desired output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find duplicates across multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149210/how-do-i-find-duplicates-across-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses window functions.  So, this works on your sample data:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by Assetno, SerialNo, StickerNo) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

I would be more inclined to use `exists`, though:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.Assetno = t.Assetno and
                    t2.SerialNo = t.SerialNo and
                    t2.StickerNo = t.StickerNo and
                    t2.location <> t.location
             );
```

This more explicitly specifies that the rows with the first three columns the same have different locations.  It is probably faster with an index on `(Assetno, SerialNo, StickerNo, location)` as well.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . Not at all.  The intention is to pick up all duplicate rows, as requested by the OP.

Comment: *"Not at all. The intention is to pick up all duplicate rows, as requested by the OP. "* indeed your right i missed that point.. Adding the `ORDER BY` as in `count(*) over (partition by Assetno, SerialNo, StickerNo ORDER BY <column>) as cnt` in this case will add unneeded processing

Comment: Thank You so much, both the methods worked like a champ.