# Find rows with duplicates in three columns without specifying value?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Ive got a table like this, where I'm looking for unnecessary duplicate rows:

[image]

I want to find any rows where the First Name, Last Name, and Occupation columns are identical - in this case rows 1 and 3. I don't want to specify what the identical values should be as I dont know.

I've tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786533/find-rows-that-have-the-same-value-on-a-column-in-mysql), but I dont think it applies to this case.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution is to add a HAVING clause where there are duplicates after grouping by all three columns

```
SELECT 
    ID, FirstName, LastName, Occupation, Age
FROM table1
GROUP BY 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Occupation
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

here is a [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763a00/1) with two duplicate rows to ensure it works properly

---

**EDIT:**

my first understanding was you wanted one row returned when it has duplicates.. if you want a query that will return all duplicate rows..
then here it is... this will return rows 1 and 3

```
SELECT p1.* FROM people p
JOIN people p1 
    ON p1.firstname = p.firstname 
    AND p1.lastname = p.lastname  
    AND p1.occupation = p.occupation
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

another [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50ad6/1)

Comment: Nice! I was trying to use some complicate `join`s, but your solution is much more elegant!

Comment: @Cynical thanks :) i've tried writing so many complicated queries just to get bested by some simple solution too lol

Comment: Your query returns rows 1 and 2, not rows 1 and 3.

Comment: @blarg it returns rows 1 and 2 because I added a duplicate for row 2. it groups rows 1 and 3 together and rows 2 and 4 together because those are duplicates.. look at the fiddle INSERT INTO TABLE part.. row 1 and 3 are duplicates and 2 and 4 are duplicates

Comment: @blarg I just edited my answer with another query... this second query will return each duplicate row.. as in it will return rows 1 and 3.. you can test it with more rows if you would like.. what I thought you wanted was just to return one row that had duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Self join, 3 times (untested): SELECT a.* from your_table a, your_table b, your_table c, your_table d
where
a.fname = b.fname and a.lname=c.lname and a.occupation=d.occupation