# I want to get a duplicate record on mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql

I want to get duplicate data in the id_time_slot field with the value "7" ?

[image: see the results of the request that I made]

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want a query that finds all the rows that have duplicate `id_time_slot`?

Comment: If that's what you want, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738346/find-rows-with-duplicates-in-three-columns-without-specifying-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquery `GROUP BY schedule_number, id_slot_time HAING COUNT(*) > 1` to get the duplicated records

in group like this:

```sql
SELECT tb1.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    tb_schedule_detail.*
  FROM
    tb_schedule_detail
    JOIN tb_scheduler ON tb_scheduler.scheduler_number = tb_schedule_detail.scheduler_number
  WHERE 
    dock_id = 2
    AND tb_schedule_detail.rdd = '2020-01-02'
  GROUP BY tb_schedule_detail.schedule_number
) AS tb1 
GROUP BY tb1.schedule_number, tb1.id_slot_time
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Salam, try to add this:

```
Select * from // before your sql request

// all your sql request 

where id_slot_time = 7; // the end
```

You will make a *Select* on your current result table ( a new table) that will give you what you want.

Comment: if I add a "where id_slot_time = 7", it will display 2 data. I only want to display 1 data only