# Postgresql: Get records having similar column values

Tags: postgresql

```
Table A

id   name   keywords
1    Obj1   a,b,c,austin black
2    Obj2   e,f,austin black,h
3    Obj3   k,l,m,n
4    Obj4   austin black,t,u,s
5    Obj5   z,r,q,w
```

I need to get those records which contains similar type of keywords. Hence the result for the table needs to be:

```
Records:
1,2,4
```

Since records **1,2,4** are the one whose some or the other keyword match with at least any other keyword.

Comment: As others will probably comment, why are you storing your keyword data in unnormalized CSV format?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes I know about that. But need to store it for some other dependencies. For the above question I thought about writing a function into the database itself that will go through each keywords and match with other. But that isn't an effective solution. Was trying for any query that could help by working around the keywords column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the "csv" to an array and then use Postgres' array functions:

```
select *
from the_table t1
where exists (select *
              from the_table t2
              where string_to_array(t1.keywords, ',') && string_to_array(t2.keywords, ',')
              and t1.id <> t2.id);
```