# from the sample database , How could I make a query where I could search all the region ( region id) where Kivuto Id is duplicated?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, having-clause

[image]

I need to fetch the 3 lines as highlighted in the result with green i.e separate region id but same kivuto id.I need to rectify such products so that I could correct the kivuto id's

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from table_name 
  where kivuto_id in (
    select email from table_name
      group by kivuto_id
      having count(*) > 1
  )
```

You can refer to this as well: [Find rows that have the same value on a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786533/find-rows-that-have-the-same-value-on-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.kivuto_id = t.kivuto_id and
                    t2.region_id <> t.region_id
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(kivuto_id, region_id)`.